# Miller Plateau - MOSFET turn ON

Tags: voltage, transistors, mosfet, switches, switching

I was looking at the MOSFET switching characteristics and stumbled upon this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1yt0s3gpcE&t=447s)

Around 8:00 of the video, the author explains that the once the threshold voltage of the MOSFET is reached, the voltage at the gate of the MOSFET does not increase. He says the voltage is clamped because the current flows through the Gate-Drain Capacitor.

I am finding difficulty in this section alone. Why should a lot of current flow through the Gate Drain capacitor or like, what causes the current flow through that capacitor during that stage. Can someone please help me with this understanding? And if the current flow direction is also indicating that the current flows through the Gate-Drain capacitor and to the Vdd supply? So, it doesn't flow through the load but only to Vdd - Why?

Request someone to clarify.

Comment: The path of current flow at the Miller Plateau isn't to Vdd, it goes through the drain-source channel (which has just formed at this point).

Comment: Thank you. But why does the current flow causing Miller Plateau ?

Comment: Because the drain voltage is dropping and Cdg needs to be charged.

Comment: I am finding difficulty over here only. If the other plate of the capacitor (connected to Vdd) , the voltage is dropping, why should there be more current flowing into the opposite plate of the capacitor?

Comment: What happens when the drain voltage drops below the gate voltage? That part should be straightforward enough. Now consider how the voltage across the capacitor changes during that time, and what causes that change.

Comment: The MOSFET will not be able to turn ON?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126897/discussion-between-newbie-and-hearth).

Comment: Why do you keep mentioning Vdd?

Comment: For an N channel MOSFET, the current that flows in the DG capacitance as the MOSFET turns on mainly flows negatively to ground through the gate-source capacitance. It is due to the MOSFET turning on which causes a rapid change in dv/dt on the drain node. That in turn injects negative current into the gate region (from the drain via gate/drain capacitance) and that temporarily holds the process up and you get the miller plateau. Basically, it's negative feedback (as soon as you get drain dv/dt, you get current in the DG capacitor and this is negative feedback).

Comment: @Andyaka, but the video explain that differently. Different sources say it differently. Can you please provide your comment as an answer. Also why does the rapid dv-dt change at the drain node, cause negative current from the drain.

Comment: Small dv/dt causes small currents to flow in a capacitor. Large dv/dt causes large currents. The negative current is because current is taken from the gate-source capacitance via gate-drain capacitance due to the falling drain-source voltage as the MOSFET turns on. This then tries to turn off the MOSFET and the process (the act of turning on the MOSFET) kinds of stalls for a few nano seconds (or longer). It's negative feedback at its heart.

Answer (score 0):

The gate capacitance is always there and does not suddenly occur when the threshold voltage is reached. The capacitance cannot clamp the gate voltage because the capacitor continues charging. Use a low enough value for the series gate resistor to charge that capacitance in the time delay that you want. NEVER use the threshold voltage for anything since that is the voltage that some Mosfets are barely turned on, they are almost turned off.